# How to concatenate a string in lotus script with (##) with forall loop?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I want to concatenate a string with multiple value with forall loop 
here is the code :

```
varAttachmentNames = Evaluate( "@AttachmentNames" , doc )
Forall strAttachmentName in varAttachmentNames
    Set object = doc.GetAttachment( strAttachmentName )
    fileName = object.Name
End Forall
```

at the end of loop if there is multiple files i want there names as abc.pdf##xyz.pdf both are seprate file names abc and xyz in fileName (string variable)

Comment: As long as you are ging to use an Evaluate function, you can concat here: Evaluate( {@Implode( @AttachmentNames , "##")} , doc )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a LOT possibilities, some not even needing the LotusScript- Loop:

First: Do the concatenation in Formula already:

```
Dim strResult as String
varAttachmentNames = Evaluate( {@Implode( @AttachmentNames , "##")} , doc )
strResult = varAttachmentNames(0)
```

Second: Use the @Implode- counterpart in LotusScript:

```
Dim strResult as String
varAttachmentNames = Evaluate( "@AttachmentNames" , doc )
strResult = Implode( varAttachmentNames, "##" )
' or with the (in other programming languages) more common alias "Join": 
'strResult = Join( varAttachmentNames, "##" )
```

Third: Use your Forall- Loop:

```
Dim strResult as String
varAttachmentNames = Evaluate( "@AttachmentNames" , doc )
Forall strAttachmentName in varAttachmentNames
    Set object = doc.GetAttachment( strAttachmentName )
    fileName = object.Name
    If strResult = "" then
        strResult = fileName
    Else
        strResult = strResult & "##" & fileName
    End If
End Forall
```